# SVG, how would I define text to apply to a Cylinder?

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

I am attempting to apply text to a 3D image of a Cylinder using HTML and SVG. I can get the text to follow a textpath or calculate dx and dy for a textspan so that it follows the curve of an ellipse but the perspective is wrong. I have seen examples with the correct perspective but they were created using a drawing program like Corel Draw and I need this to work in a responsive Web site.

The textpath bends the text vertically so for example an L is just tilted at the outer edges of the cylinder where the vertical part of the L should stay parallel to the sides of the cylinder.

Using textspan with dx and dy attributes keeps the vertical part of an L vertical but the base does not follow the elliptical path.

The text I am writing to the cylinder is fairly limited so I could possibly pre-process it into a set of glyphs but there is too many possibilities to do this manually.

I appreciate any tips offered on how to make this look visually correct.

-- edited --
Based on the comments I now realize that even though I can fake a 3D image there is no z axis so to make this work correctly I might need to generate the graphic using something that supports 3D images. If I use something like that ideally it would allow for a responsive feel.

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/9bzaytnj/

```
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <ellipse cx="65" cy="50" rx="60" ry="15" id="lid"></ellipse>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(80,80,80)"></stop>
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="rgb(255,255,255)"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(80,80,80)"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <ellipse cx="65" cy="70" rx="60" ry="15" id="bottom"></ellipse>
      <rect x="5" y="50" width="120" height="20" id="face"></rect>
      <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#bottom"></use>
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#face"></use>
      </clipPath>
      <path id="myTextPath" d="M5,62.5 a35,9 0 1,0 120,0"></path>
    </defs>
    <rect x="5" y="50" width="120" height="35" fill="url(#gradient)" clip-path="url(#clip)"></rect>
    <use fill="grey" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#lid"></use>
    <text style="font-size:10">
      <textPath anchor="middle" startoffset="20%" xlink:href="#myTextPath" >LX HHH LL HHH</textPath>
    </text>
    <path d="M5,70 a35,9 0 1,0 120,0" style="stroke:#660000; fill:none;"></path>
  </svg>
```

Comment: SVG is a 2d technology, it has no 3d capabilities.

Comment: is your 3D image a 2D representation ? So it isn't actually 3D ? Also can you provide a JSFiddle of what you have tried ? That way we can try things out ourselves :)

Comment: I now realize that I may need to consider generating the images and then placing them in my page. Since these can be pre-generated and then just scaled as necessary it may not be too bad. I will begin researching this -- many many years ago I had to use a headless Java Runtime to do something similar, maybe this will require similar treatment. I would appreciate any tips on where to begin.